# Having trouble styling my Rails select menu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to change the font of a select menu but I’m having trouble doing it.  I installed the “bootstrap-sass” gem and added this to my stylesheet …

```
select {
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}
```

and then set up my select tag this way

```
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select([["Select State", nil], *us_states]), {class: "form-control"} %>
```

but when my menu is rendered the options continue to have the normal font and not the one I specified.  What else do I need to do to style my Rails select menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select([["Select State", nil], *us_states]), class: 'states form-control' %>
```

You don't need to send it in a secondary hash.

I'd also consider adding a more identifiable class name for example:

```
.states {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
```

}